# Host dependent resources in TomEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am developing a web application using EJB in TomEE.

To separate development, test, and production environments of the application, I use different `<Host>` entries in `server.xml`. So the environments can be chosen by different URLs, like `dev.myapp.example.tld` and `test.myapp.example.tld`.

The resources (at this moment database connections) are defined in `tomee.xml` as

```
<Resource id="myappDatabaseDevelopment" type="DataSource"> ...

<Resource id="myappDatabaseTest" type="DataSource"> ...
```

Now, the app in the test host shall access the test database, same for dev host and dev database. But that's a clumsy solution, as the two resources have different `id`s, so I have to decide in the Java code, depending on the environment it's running in, which persistence unit to choose. It would be preferable to manage this by container configuration. But I can't find any way to specify in the TomEE config files which resource is to be used in which host. `server.xml` has hosts, `tomee.xml` has resources, but no way to reference one from the other.

Somehow, TomEE appears to recognize the different hosts, however. When I deploy the two versions of the same app under the same host, but different app (context) names, I get errors because of duplicate deployment ids, plus lots of trouble because of mixing container managed beans between the two apps. Using different hosts (and different `appBase`s) makes those errors go away.

Is there any way to have multiple configurations of a resource, having the same `id`, depending on the host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1449, adding host in the deployment id should be enough.

Comment: I use this, and the server allows me to deploy the same app twice, therefore. But how do I configure each database resource defined in `tomee.xml` so that one is used in one of these apps (development), and the other in the other one (test)?

Comment: using resources.xml can be an option but an alternative which is really simpler is to deploy the application a single time and use a dynamic router to select the database to use from a filter: http://tomee.apache.org/dynamic-datasource.html

Comment: The dynamic router approach, according to the "Dynamic Datasource" example you quote, lets me code the decision which resource to take in my Java code. That's what I'm doing just now (in a simpler way), but it means to put environment knowledge into the application code. I'd like to get rid of that. Similarly, the `resources.xml` approach would mean to deploy a different config file, dependent on the environment to which I deploy. I'm looking for a way to configure all environment knowledge in the container, not in my Java code or IDE.

Comment: this is half true since this code can be deployed in the container (typically a jar in tomee/lib and a filter in conf/web.xml to enforce the tenant/datasource to use)

Comment: That's the clue, thanks. Hope I'll get it right, otherwise I'll come back with more questions.